# Getting a stack overflow/infinite loop crash out from this code, don't know why

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

I'm querying a database then building a HTML table with the results, but when I assign the returned string to InnerHtml of a container div, I get an "unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'"

```
    Using db As New AdoHelper()

        Dim builder As New StringBuilder
        builder.Append("<table class='table table-striped table-hover' data-toggle='table'><thead><tr><th>.......</th></tr></thead>")
        Using rdr As SqlDataReader = db.ExecDataReader(qry)
            ' Get row of data from rdr
            While rdr.Read()
                builder.Append("<tbody><tr><td>")
                builder.Append(rdr(rdr.GetName(0)))
                builder.Append("</td>")
                builder.Append("<td>")
                builder.Append(rdr(rdr.GetName(1)))
                builder.Append("</td>")
                builder.Append("<td>")
                builder.Append(rdr(rdr.GetName(2)))
                builder.Append("</td>")
                builder.Append("<td>")
                builder.Append(rdr(rdr.GetName(3)))
                builder.Append("</td>")
                builder.Append("<td>")
                builder.Append(rdr(rdr.GetName(4)))
                builder.Append("</td>")
                builder.Append("<td>")
                builder.Append(rdr(rdr.GetName(5)))
                builder.Append("</td>")
                builder.Append("</tr>")
            End While
        End Using
        builder.Append("</tbody></table>")
        Return builder.ToString
    End Using
```

Comment: I don't *think* it will help but you should move `Dim builder As New StringBuilder` to before the first `Using` and the `Return builder.ToString` to after the last `End Using`.

Comment: Look in the `Call Stack` window of the VS debugger when the exception is thrown. It will help you identify which method called which, and which one(s) keep calling the same over and over again. See: [**How to: Use the Call Stack Window**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx).

Comment: If you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) it will point out some problems with the code for you. If you fix them then you might have working code.

Comment: @VisualVincent Call Stack says [External Code] followed by   The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded.

Comment: @AndrewMorton i turned that on and it hasnt picked up on any errors

Comment: how many rows are returned by rdp?

Comment: You should probably add more code then, as this small piece isn't enough to reproduce the issue. Make sure that no event handlers or anything gets called when you change the `InnerHtml`.

Comment: @user1765369 My mistake: I thought that stringbuilder.Append(object) would be a problem, but it turns out that there is an overload for that. So I thought that if there was a problem there, there could be problems elsewhere. Sorry.

Comment: it seems a recursion error

Comment: @VisualVincent this is basically all the code. It is jut this function and Page_Load which fires off the function and assigns the resulting string to InnerHtml

Comment: have you tried what happens if you forces to use only one row?

Comment: @mcNets I was just in the middle of testing that! I tried with 5 rows and it works fine. So the issue is clearly in the number of rows, but I need to display all these rows!

Comment: The html part doesn't looks right, you keep adding <tbody> at the beginning of iteration of loop. But does it cause your error, I don' t know.

Comment: @PaulL duh! that... seems to have fixed it? But I am surprised because I wouldn't expect invalid HTML like that to throw a programming error

Comment: As @PaulL points, there are a lot of <tbody> and only one </tbody> Try to open <tbody> outside of wile

Comment: @user1765369, surprise to me as well :D

Comment: How many records is your query returning?

Answer (score 0):

Test this for your html table. I didn't test the code. but the html wasnot correct.

```
 builder.Append("<table class='table table-striped table-hover' data-toggle='table'><thead><tr><th>.......</th></tr></thead>")
    Using rdr As SqlDataReader = db.ExecDataReader(qry)
        ' Get row of data from rdr
        While rdr.Read()
            builder.Append("<tr><td>")
            builder.Append(rdr(rdr.GetName(0)))
            builder.Append("</td>")
            builder.Append("<td>")
            builder.Append(rdr(rdr.GetName(1)))
            builder.Append("</td>")
            builder.Append("<td>")
            builder.Append(rdr(rdr.GetName(2)))
            builder.Append("</td>")
            builder.Append("<td>")
            builder.Append(rdr(rdr.GetName(3)))
            builder.Append("</td>")
            builder.Append("<td>")
            builder.Append(rdr(rdr.GetName(4)))
            builder.Append("</td>")
            builder.Append("<td>")
            builder.Append(rdr(rdr.GetName(5)))
            builder.Append("</td>")
            builder.Append("</tr>")
        End While
    End Using
```